# Find matching MD5 and XML in a directory

Tags: shell-script, filenames

Do you know what bash script I can use to search or find out if a directory has both MD5 and XML? The issue is some users sometimes forget to send both MD5 and XML. If one file is missing in a directory then the directory is not processed. The below is not satisfactorily working.

```
while read f; do echo "\"$f\""; done < <(ls -1) >> /tmp/log3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for pairs of files - one named '.xml' and the other named '.md5' I would tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file ( glob ( "/path/to/dir/*.xml" ) ) {
   print "MD5 is missing for $file\n" unless -f $file =~ s/\.xml$/\.md5/r;
}
```

Or as a one liner:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", grep { not -f s/\.xml$/\.md5/r } glob ( "/path/to/*.xml" )'
```

Both do basically the same thing

- use `glob` to expand a shell pattern and get a matching file list of `xml` files.
- Then use a (sed style) replace pattern, to turn the `.xml` extension to a `.md5` - the `r` flag means 'return this value' (rather than modifying the pattern) so we can use it inline as a filename...
- to hand to `-f` filetest, to check if it exists.
- And then print the "missing" files if there isn't a matching one.

This should be pretty trivial to adapt to test for missing XML for md5s as well.

Following on frmo commments - if you're getting: `"Bareword found where operator expected at ./file_list.pl line 6, near "s/\.xml$/\.md5/r" syntax error at ./file_list.pl line 6, near "s/\.xml$/\.md5/r"` Execution of ./file_list.pl aborted due to compilation errors" thta means you're using an older version of perl that doesn't support the `r` flag to regex.

This was added in perl 5.14 in 2011.

As a workaround:

```
my $xml_file = $file;
   $xml_file =~ s/\.xml$/\.md5/; 
print "MD5 is missing for $file\n" unless -f $xml_file =~ s/\.xml$/\.md5/r;
```

Comment: Im getting the error message:- 

Bareword found where operator expected at ./file_list.pl line 6, near "s/\.xml$/\.md5/r" syntax error at ./file_list.pl line 6, near "s/\.xml$/\.md5/r" Execution of ./file_list.pl aborted due to compilation errors

Comment: You've an older version of perl then I think. the `r` flag requires something slightly newer. I'll edit a workaround into the answer.

Comment: Sobrique,did you manage to find the workaround/

Comment: Yes. It's the bottom lines of the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to detect when there are missing files; either that an `.md5` file is missing or if an `.xml` file is missing.

Loop over the patterns `*.md5` and `*.xml` in turn and detect the corresponding file of the "other type":

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for name in ./*.md5; do
    if [ ! -e "${name%.md5}.xml" ]; then
        printf '"%s" is missing its XML file\n' "$name"
    fi
done

for name in ./*.xml; do
    if [ ! -e "${name%.xml}.md5" ]; then
        printf '"%s" is missing its MD5 file\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

The expansion `${variable%word}` would expand to the value of `$variable`, with the (shortest) string matching `word` removed from the end of it.  We are using it here to remove the known filename suffix from value of the loop variable.  We then append the other suffix to the variable's value and test whether that makes the name of an existing file.  If not, an appropriate message is printed.

Testing it:

```
$ touch file{1..5}.xml file{2..7}.md5
$ ls
file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml file4.xml file5.xml file7.md5
file2.md5 file3.md5 file4.md5 file5.md5 file6.md5 script
```

```
$ sh script
"./file6.md5" is missing its XML file
"./file7.md5" is missing its XML file
"./file1.xml" is missing its MD5 file
```